# get detail email info Gmail API

Tags: gmail, google-api

I can able to get the list of unread emails via [https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/] using the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed).

but using that , I can only get a brief info of an email message like ( to, from, subject and summary ).

If I want to get CC, BCC, and attachment info , how can I get using the Gmail API ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to get that functionality with GMAIL API. So I use IMAP to authenticate with Oauth Token and use IMAP instead.